# how to set up a wallpaper app using firebase recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-adapter, android-wallpaper

I created a wallpaper app ,I'm using `Firebase` to upload images to a database and shown it to `RecyclerView`.

I can see the images that I uploaded in `Firebase` through the `RecyclerView` and I can also pass that image to a another activity.

but my problem is, I can't set the image as wallpaper, when I set the button the image is disappearing.

my code to set wallpaper:

```
 img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.images);
    Intent intent  = getIntent();
    String webUrl = intent.getStringExtra("URL");
    Picasso.get().load(webUrl).into(img);

    fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            WallpaperManager wallpaper = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
               wallpaper.setResource(+ R.drawable.pug);  //by using this code i can set a image in directory a wallpaper
                //wallpaper.setResource(+ R.id.images); //i tried this one it doesn't work it just crashes the app

            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

what I want is to set any image shown in the `ImageView`
is there any way

Comment: you can set image direct into imageview.

Comment: how to code that

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already have the permission in place for this:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I am assuming you want the user to choose an image from the list and set it as wallpaper. 
You can only pass a `Bitmap` or `Resource ID` to `WallpaperManager`. In this case, fetch the image as a `Bitmap` first, and then load into the `ImageView`.

Since you are already using Picasso, you can do this:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(webUrl).centerCrop().into(new Target() { 
    @Override 
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) { 
        wallpaper.setBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: i wan to set the image in imageview as wallpaper on the onclick i gave here ```    public void onClick(View view) {
            WallpaperManager wallpaper = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
               wallpaper.setResource(+ R.drawable.pug);  //by using this code i can set a image in directory a wallpaper
                //wallpaper.setResource(+ R.id.images); //i tried this one it doesn't work it just crashes the app

            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }```

Comment: That's what I just explained above. Put my code inside `onClick` method.